# how i can Make my dashboard protected component (Only registered user have access).And how dashboard navigation work

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom, dashboard, mern

I am developing a react app in which i need a user dashboard where user can view his tweets.and other tasks.

### Steps which i have completed so far.

1. authentication of users using rest api(node js,mongodb) is done.
2. Login/sign up is completed
3. Storing jwt token in browser storage.

### My app components/pages are.

1. Home(can be accessible by all users)
2. About us(public can be access by all users)
3. Dashboard(protected only accessible by registered user)
4. Dashboard nested components like profile,search tweet etc.(protected )

### **Problems that i am facing.**

1. how jwt will use to access only my protected pages and also public pages
2. how i make my dashboard navigation (nested navigation) .

Comment: I have a client that insists to hide the dashboard Design even if it is useless - for security reasons - and that is also a valid reason to protect the dashboard .. sometimes NEXTJS is a valid alternative .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a withAuth component:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const withAuth = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const router = useRouter();

      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

      if (!accessToken) {
        router.replace('/login');
        return null;
      }

      return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }
    return null;
  };
};

export default withAuth;
```

And when you want to "protect" a page or component you can wrap the export with the withAuth component like this:

```
import withAuth from '../withAuth'

const Component = () => {
 return (
   <div></div>
 )
}

export default withAuth(Component)
```

Comment: but i want to redirect to login or home page if user is not authenticated.

Comment: i understand you.But it only return to login page by doing this.

Comment: if (!token) {
    return < Login /> || <Home />

  }this is my code.

Comment: What do you mean login page or home page? You have to choose one.

Comment: i have to pages one for login and one for home .A unregistered user can access both .problem is when user is not authenticated it only redirecting to login and not able to access home page.

Comment: When you do what i said, that wont happen. Read my answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236178/discussion-between-salik-saleem-and-jonas-hendel).

Comment: localStorage for any sensitive data is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom route component like this example,

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) =>
            localStorage.getItem("userToken")
             ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/Login" />
          }
        />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and use this component as

```
<PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} path="/Dashboard" exact />
```

The PrivateRoute.js will check if user is there in localstorage. If user is not present, it will redirect to /Login

**Publicroute.js**

```
function PublicRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) =>
            localStorage.getItem("userToken")? <Redirect to="/Dashboard" /> : <Component {...props} /> 
          }
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and use this component as

```
<PublicRoute component={Login} path="/Login" />
```

when you hits /Login and if user is already logged in, PublicRoute.js will take you to your component, else will redirect to /Login page.

This does the trick

```
localStorage.getItem("userToken")? <Redirect to="/Dashboard" /> : <Component {...props} />
```

Comment: user is moving to login but user is unable to acces home page by this method.it is only accessing login.I want to access both

Comment: You can create a <PrivateRoute /> for all restricted routes and a <PublicRoute/> component for all the public components

Comment: kindly suggest some tutorial or article about how to make them both

Comment: Ive added publicRoute as well. You can refer this as well. 
 https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your routes by wrapping the route in a HOC and this HOC will have your auth verification logic baked into it.
Here's How:

we have 2 routes

1. Home screen (public)
2. Dashboard (private)

Your router would look like: (Keeping it minimal)

```
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute path="/dash">
            <Dashboard />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

Here, PrivateRoute is an HOC Which takes a screen, and based on auth logic, either renders the screen or redirects user to desired location / shows UI.

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({children, ...props}) => {
   const auth = checkForTheToken();
   if(auth) return children
   return <Redirect to="/login" />
}
```